# Implementing a namespace without a class in C++

Tags: c++, namespaces

Should be an easy question, but I am struggling right now for a hour to wrap some helper functions in a namespace.
Since I need need helper functions that do not have to be inside a class, I was recommend to wrap them into a namespace instead of making all of them static. See also here: http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines

The problem is, whatever I do, I run into different errors. So whats the right way to write functions with a own namespace without creating a class? Lets take the following example. I tried already different variations of it.

My header file:

```
#ifndef BINARYCONVERTER_HPP
#define BINARYCONVERTER_HPP

#include <iostream>

namespace binary_converter {
    int myFunction(void);
}

#endif
```

And my source file:

```
#include "binary_converter.hpp"

int myFunction(void) {
    return true;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You are missing `namespace binary_converter {...};` in source file

Comment: what are "different errors" ? Please include them in the question

Comment: btw also if you write a class with methods (static or not) you better put it inside a namespace (not the global one)

Comment: @idclev463035818  I am curious, why should I use a namespace, the class itself already forms a namespace.

Comment: because namespaces help to organize your code. Maybe today you have only one class called `Foo`, but maybe tomorrow you have a `project1::Foo` and a `project2::Foo`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As said in the C++ [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace):

> Symbols declared inside a namespace block are placed in a named scope
>   that prevents them from being mistaken for identically-named symbols
>   in other scopes.

Having that in mind function `myFunction` from your header file and funtion `myFunction` from your source file are not part of the same namespace. Function from the header file is part of the `binary_converter` namespace while function from the source file is part of global namespace.

Therefore, you need to wrap your function

```cpp
int myFunction() {
    return 0;
}
```

from the source file into a `binary_converter` namespace like this:

```cpp
namespace binary_converter {
    int myFunction() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

or use scope operator to note that `myFunction` belongs to `binary_converter` namespace like this:

```cpp
int binary_converter::myFunction() {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or `int binary_converter::myFunction() { return 0; }`. Your approach is generally better. +1.

Comment: @PeteBecker I will add this also as an update to my answer. Thanks

Comment: @NutCracker Thanks for your post. I already tried that. Just realized I forgot to update my include-path, that why the linker could not find the reference.

Comment: @muella91 you can anyway accept the answer since it solves the problem from the question